# python: run script from different directories

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, file-io, directory

I am trying to modify my operating system with a python3 script, therefore it needs to run from my home directory.

Command:

```
python3 PycharmProjects/saveclipboard/main.py
```

but either

```
import os
os.getcwd()
```

as well as

```
from os import path
path.dirname(path.abspath("__file__"))
```

return `home/laptop` instead of `home/laptop/PycharmProjects/saveclipboard` when the script is called in my home directory. Calling the script in the sripts directory with `python3 main.py` successfully returns `home/laptop/PycharmProjects/saveclipboard`.

**How to get the scripts absolute path, to open files with `open(getabsolutepathsomehow() + "foo.bar", "w")` in its directory, when the script does get called in another directory?**

Comment: The latter should work if you use `__file__` rather than `"__file__"`. But the current working directory can be entirely different from the directory where the script resides.

Comment: With those unwanted quotes, it was treating it as the path of a file literally called `__file__` (even if such a file does not actually exist) -- and because this does not start with `/` it is a relative path i.e. in the current directory.

Comment: yes, that solves it, thanks! :)